# Preview pdf in iframe do not download

Tags: html, pdf, iframe

I have a basic html code to preview some pdf

```
<iframe src="file.pdf" />
```

But from time to time, should depend on the user browser config the file is downloaded and nothing is displayed in the preview. Is there any way to force the preview ?

I also tried

```
<object data="file.pdf" type="application/pdf">
  <embed src="file.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

But not compatible on all browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the older way of doing it. Now these methods have started to be deprecated.

Few methods by which you can implement this is:

- Google Docs Embed
  You can upload the file on google docs and get the embed link from the share option and embed it into the site using iframe.
- Pdf.js
  This is a library in javascript that helps in dealing with pdf files.